# Amplitude modulator for a sine wave generator

Tags: design, modulation, function-generator

I have a home made, mostly using the design in a magazine article, radio frequency signal generator, and I would like to be able to modulate (AM) the sine wave output, which is up to 8 MHz, with an audio sine wave. Is there a simple design for a module that I can insert in the output lead to accomplish this?

Comment: Making AM is easier if the circuit that produces the carrier originally can be modulated.  You don't want to modulate the carrier power signal after the fact.  Show the schematic of what you have, then suggestions could be possible about how to add modulation.

Comment: Thank you @Olin. I want to use the resultant AM modulated wave as input to a test circuit, not for radiation as a radio wave, so, very little power is involved. The circuit consists of a signal generator, connected to a DUT via a coaxial cable, and I want to insert the modulator in that cable.

Comment: Any follow-up on this? On a separate note, both in the year 2012 and 2020, a microcontroller's PWM followed by an RLC seems like the simples quickest future-proofest cheapest solution.